How can I use admob in dynamic feature module?
When I use admob in dynamic feature module, the project built failed.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.quik.testpfd.admod'
    compileSdk PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":TestPlayFeatureDelivery")
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'
}

[Some Errors]
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\29807\Documents\workspace\Cocos\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\build\android\proj\build\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:113: error: resource xml/gma_ad_services_config (aka com.quik.testpfd:xml/gma_ad_services_config) not found.
C:\Users\29807\Documents\workspace\Cocos\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\build\android\proj\build\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:135: error: resource bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default (aka com.quik.testpfd:bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default) not found.
C:\Users\29807\Documents\workspace\Cocos\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\build\android\proj\build\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:140: error: resource bool/enable_system_job_service_default (aka com.quik.testpfd:bool/enable_system_job_service_default) not found.
C:\Users\29807\Documents\workspace\Cocos\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\build\android\proj\build\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:146: error: resource bool/enable_system_foreground_service_default (aka com.quik.testpfd:bool/enable_system_foreground_service_default) not found.
C:\Users\29807\Documents\workspace\Cocos\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\build\android\proj\build\TestPlayFeatureDelivery\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:207: error: resource bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default (aka com.quik.testpfd:bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.


I suppose that it works in dynamic feature module.


I try this solution and fixed the problem.
solution
